# how do you transpose more than 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for the stupid question. How do you transpose more than 2 matrices.

i.e. $(ABCDE)'=$

Comment: This is akin to the socks-shoes property. Write the product in reverse order with transposes.

Comment: so it will be E'D'C'B'A'

Comment: @user9903833 Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

if $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$ and matrix multipication is associative.

$(ABCDE)^T = (A(BCDE))^T = (BCDE)^TA^T$ and keep repeating down the chain.